# What resolution to use with "time ago" labels

Tags: ios, datetime, time

I have an app that shows certain states of hardware. I know the time when the hardware entered said state (failed, active, idle, unconnected, etc). I've been experimenting with showing the state with an "ago" time. But I've struggled with how to adjust the resolution.

Under an hour is easy, just show "minutes ago". As you move into hours ago though, the minutes become less and less important. I'm not sure that suddenly jumping to "1 hour ago" at 61 minutes is the right way though. And when to switch to "2 hours ago". Do you round, or truncated that computation. The same dilemma exists at the 24 hour point. Do you show 25 hours ago, or just say 1 day ago. Or should there be a period where I show "1 hour and 13 minutes ago" and then at some point drop the minutes.

I know these "ago" labels aren't original. I'm curious how others have implemented this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js is a very popular library used in web development that can output [time from now](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) just as you are asking. Below is a listing of how they break down their intervals into a more digestible format.

From their documentation:

- 0 to 45 seconds `seconds ago`
- 45 to 90 seconds `a minute ago`
- 90 seconds to 45 minutes `2 minutes ago ... 45 minutes ago`
- 45 to 90 minutes `an hour ago`
- 90 minutes to 22 hours `2 hours ago ... 22 hours ago`
- 22 to 36 hours `a day ago`
- 36 hours to 25 days `2 days ago ... 25 days ago`
- 25 to 45 days `a month ago`
- 45 to 345 days `2 months ago ... 11 months ago`
- 345 to 547 days (1.5 years) `a year ago`
- 548 days+ `2 years ago ... 20 years ago`

Comment: Sorry for the belated accept. Thought I had a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

As a sumplement to @JimmyBoh 's answer, I thought I'd add the ObjectiveC code I used:

```
#import "NSDate+AgoPrint.h"

#define SECONDS(s) (s)
#define MINUTES(m) ((m) * 60)
#define HOURS(h) ((h) * 3600)
#define DAYS(d) ((d) * 3600 * 24)
#define YEARS(y) ((y) * 3600 * 24 * 365)

@implementation NSDate (AgoPrint)

- (NSString*) simpleAgoString {
    NSTimeInterval ago = -self.timeIntervalSinceNow;
    if (ago <= SECONDS(45)) { // 0 to 45 seconds seconds ago
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u seconds ago", (unsigned int)round(ago)];
    }
    else if (ago <= SECONDS(90)) { //45 to 90 seconds a minute ago
        return @"a minute ago";
    }
    else if (ago <= MINUTES(45)) { //90 seconds to 45 minutes 2 minutes ago ... 45 minutes ago
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u minutes ago", (unsigned int)round(ago / MINUTES(1))];
    }
    else if (ago <= MINUTES(90)) { // 45 to 90 minutes an hour ago
        return @"an hour ago";
    }
    else if (ago <= HOURS(22)) { // 90 minutes to 22 hours 2 hours ago ... 22 hours ago
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u hours ago", (unsigned int)round(ago / HOURS(1))];
    }
    else if (ago <= HOURS(36)) { // 22 to 36 hours a day ago
        return @"a day ago";
    }
    else if (ago <= DAYS(25)) { // 36 hours to 25 days 2 days ago ... 25 days ago
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u days ago", (unsigned int)round(ago / DAYS(1))];
    }
    else if (ago <= DAYS(45)) { // 25 to 45 days a month ago
        return @"a month ago";
    }
    else if (ago <= DAYS(345)) { // 45 to 345 days 2 months ago ... 11 months ago
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u months ago", (unsigned int)round(ago / DAYS(30))];
    }
    else if (ago < DAYS(547)) { // 345 to 547 days (1.5 years) a year ago
        return @"a year ago";
    }
    else { // 548 days+ 2 years ago ... 20 years ago
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u years ago", (unsigned int)round(ago / YEARS(1))];
    }
}
@end
```

I may end up adding weeks or replacing months or weeks, but the general approach seems pretty clear how I would slot that in.